# Optimize a distance matrix calculation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Im trying to calculate a matrix distance from a Fourier transformation for the first two components. The matrix is a 40k by 40k and the way im doing it is extremely slow. Is there a way to calculate the matrix is a more efficient faster way?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import dft

#Transform the data using Fourier Transform.
ft = norm_data.dot(dft(8).transpose())/sqrt(8)

def ft_distance_calc(x,y):
    temp = np.zeros((x,y))
    for i in range(x):
        for z in range(y):
            temp[i,z] = sqrt(np.square(abs(ft[i,0:2] - ft[z,0:2])).sum())
    return temp

ft_distance = ft_distance_calc(40000,40000)
```

Comment: You should probably try to calculate over entire np.arrays, instead of specific cells,it will be much faster. That nested loop causes this huge delay

Comment: @archer Not a good advice. You still can prevent looping and do array-based calculation on selected columns.

Comment: What is `norm_data`? please provide minimal example for it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in functions for it:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
def ft_distance_calc_2(x,y):
    return cdist(ft[:x,0:2],ft[:y,0:2])
```

---

**Comparison** using `benchit`:

```
#OP's solution
def ft_distance_calc(x,y):
    temp = np.zeros((x,y))
    for i in range(x):
        for z in range(y):
            temp[i,z] = np.sqrt(np.square(abs(ft[i,0:2] - ft[z,0:2])).sum())
    return temp

#@Ehsan's solution
def ft_distance_calc_2(x,y):
    return cdist(ft[:x,0:2],ft[:y,0:2])

#@Quang's solution
def dist_cal(x,y):
    return np.sqrt(np.square(ft[:x,None, :2]-ft[None, :y, :2]).sum(-1))

ft = np.random.rand(1000,2)
in_ = {n:[n, n] for n in [10,100,1000]}
```

Seems like `ft_distance_calc_2` is the fastest.

[image]

Comment: the problem with cdist which is what i was using is that the matrix is composed of complex numbers, and the distance cant be calculated because c dist keep the complex component of the dft matrix used for the transformation.

Comment: @djj I am not sure if I understand what you mean? do you want the complex distance? if so how do you define it? Also, in `cdist` you have the option of defining your distance function `measure`. Another approach is using `np.linalg.norm` which is probably also pretty fast. If you provide us with a minimal example of data and desired output we can help better. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about a broadcasting

```
def dist_cal(x,y):
    return np.sqrt(np.square(ft[:x,None, :2]-ft[None, :y, :2]).sum(-1))

# test
a = ft_distance_calc(400,200)
b = dist_cal(400,200)

(np.abs(a-b) < 1e-6).all()
# True
```